# Javascript Syntax Error With Sequence "<%...%>" in Internet Explorer Only

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm defining two tokens in Javascript comprised of arbitrary characters (generated by a server-side script).

If `token1` happens to include the sequence `<%` and `token2` the sequence `%>`, Internet Explorer states that the `token1` line has a syntax error -- but only if each variable is defined within its own `<script>` block.

For example, this is OK:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var token1 = "xxxx<%xxx";
    var token2 = "x%>xxxxxx";
</script>
```

But this is invalid:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var token1 = "xxxx<%xxx";
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var token2 = "x%>xxxxxx";
</script>
```

Both methods are reported as valid markup in Firefox using the HTML Validator extension, and no errors are reported in the Error Console.

Also, I've noticed that I can workaround this issue in IE by encoding the percent sign as `\045` or `\x25` for these sequences, or if I split the strings before/after the percent sign accordingly:

```
var token1 = "xxxx<\045xxx";
var token1 = "xxxx<" + "%xxx";
```

But I'd welcome some feedback on why this is happening to defend against other by chance errors.

Thanks.

Comment: are you running this in a server like JSP or ASP?

Comment: what versions of these browsers are you running?

Comment: @logan-murphy This is being run on an ActiveState PerlEx server, but I can reproduce the issue when downloaded and viewed on my local harddrive using IE6 and IE8.

Comment: Looks to be a bug in IE's parser, possibly due to shared code with IIS or a planned feature that never appeared. Take a look at the document structure in IE's inspector; what I see in IE8 is that the separate script elements in the 2nd example are parsed as a single element. As another clue, add an `<% alert('% tag') %>` before or after all the `<script>`s and it gets transformed to `<!-- lert('%tag') -->` [sic].